# Toggle function on multiple UL's

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

So what I'm currently having is multiple DIV's with all separate UL's in them. The LI's inside them are all set to display:none. When the arrow (fa icon) is being clicked, the corresponding LI should open with a toggle function and the 'fa fa-chevron-down should' should turn into a 'fa fa-chevron-up' Now for some reason I can't get this to work properly, could anyone help me with this? HTML used below:

```
<div class="filter-col">
    <div class="filter size clearfix">
        <b>Size <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></b>
        <ul class="filter Size">
            <li>
                5
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>

    <div class="filter width clearfix">
        <b>Width <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></b>
        <ul class="filter width">
            <li>
                3E
            </li>
            <li>
                D
            </li>
            <li>
                E
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="filter style clearfix">
        <b>Style <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></b>
        <ul class="filter style">
            <li>
                Shoes
            </li>
            <li>
                Sandals
            </li>
            <li>
                Boots
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And in the CSS where I set the display to none:

```
ul.filter li{display:none;}
```

edit; and the script currently being used:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fa").click(function(){
            $("ul.filter li").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

So currently all the LI's will toggle, and that is not what I want obviously.

Comment: Can you also include the javascript or jQuery code you have tried?

Comment: Added the code, but I don't think it's really helpfull

Comment: Your code is not changing the icons from down to up like you want it to. Also there is nothing to show that you are changing the `display: none`.

Comment: I wasen't sure how to do that and only started thinking of that when I was typing the question so that's why I didn't start putting it in the code yet.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the function to show the `li`'s when you click on the `fa-chevron-down` icon:

```
$(".fa-chevron-down").click(function(e){
    $(e.target).removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
    $(e.target).addClass('fa-chevron-up');
    $(e.target).parent().find('li').slideToggle("slow");
    $(e.target).parent().find('li').css('display' ,'list-item');
});
```

Above, `e` is the click event itself.

And for the opposite interaction:

```
$(".fa-chevron-up").click(function(e){
    $(e.target).removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
    $(e.target).addClass('fa-chevron-down');
    $(e.target).parent().find('li').slideToggle("slow");
    $(e.target).parent().find('li').css('display' ,'none');
});
```

I suggest looking into the api documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/8aups5o3/3/) is a working demo

Comment: Thanks for the help. But still every li is being toggled when clicked and the chevron's only change once.